# html/css How can I show the clicked photo in a gallery at the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

I want to make 1 html page a gallery for my website.  Instead of making a page for the title and description of every picture, I would like to show the information of the last clicked image above the gallery.  (pics of video game items and how/where to obtain them, to be specific)

Basically when you go to the website, you will see a blank image spot, a description that says "click one below" and a gallery below.  Once an image is clicked, it scrolls you back to the top and changes the blank image spot and description to the relevant picture.

This would save me from creating 100+ pages for each dedicated item and description, without clogging 1 page with TONS of information.  Thanks

(preferably with only html/css because that's all I know, but a simple copy pasta of something else would help as well)

Comment: I don't believe this can be done without javascript/jquery or equivalent

Comment: I found i can change the picture with some javascript code but knowing nothing about javascript, idk how to change the text above and below it.  
    <script>
    function pictureChange()
    {
    document.getElementById(id here).src=pic here;
    }
    </script>  is how im changing it

Comment: You can write text/html content to a div in a similar way